# Using ADB backup for app databases

Tags: adb, backup

I'm having an issue with the backup, I did it fine yesterday and managed to back up the folder that contained the databases. I then successfully converted the `backup.ab` file to a backup.tar file and got to see the files. Today however, every time I do the adb backup command and allow the 'back up my data' option on the device all I seem to get is a 1kb file.

In the time in between the two back ups the device has had no wi-fi connection and been on aeroplane mode, therefore it can not have updated the app to change the 'android:allowbackup' to become false.

I am trying to pull off all kik messenger databases using ADB, the device is rooted but Kik.android is not debuggable so i cant seem to use the "run-as" method.

I am using the following commands:

```
adb backup -noapk /data/data/kik.android/databases/
```

What am I doing wrong???

I have included a screenshot, on the left is the first backup I did and that I got the databases fine, the command prompt shows that the files are there on the device and the command I used and the bottom window shows the output of the `backup.ab` file being a 1kb file.

Please help as its driving me crazy. [image]

Comment: Can you try `adb backup -f kik.ab -noapk kik.android`? Should result in a file called `kik.ab` which should be larger than 1kb. I wonder how your quoted command could have succeeded before – as `adb backup` expects the package name as parameter, not some directory name.

Comment: Exactly, @kelvingoodram may have confused adb backup with adb pull. (But with adb pull, you might have permission issues.)